# Question bot.js - if command is used then bot will DM you questions one by one, and later print out answers to certain channel

Tags: node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

im working on a bot that asks you questions, and later prints out answers for moderators to certain channel. So far bug report questions. So if command !report -testbug is used, then after that bot will start DMing you questions one by one. And after all the questions are answered, bot will print out embed form of user answers to channel. Everything works fine, but one thing. If 2 or more users are reporting at the same time, then the answers are getting mixed together. And i have no idea how to fix that. Im using global array to save answers and later print them out, that could be the problem, but if i tried to use local array, then that didnt work for me. (i used comments, so its easier to understand)

````
let userApplications = {}
let repliestemp = []; // THE ARRAY WHERE ANSWERS ARE GETTING SAVED

client.on("message", function(message) {

  let authorId = message.author.id;
  if (message.content === "!report -testbug") { // THE COMMAND
      console.log(`Apply begin for authorId ${authorId}`);
      client.channels.get('652930225973362718');
      message.delete();
      // User is not already in a registration process    
      if (!(authorId in userApplications)) {
          userApplications[authorId] = { "step" : 1}

          message.author.send("```We need to ask some questions before we can start investigating the bug```");
          message.author.send("```Please answer these few questions in order to successfully report an in-game issue.```");
          message.author.send("```Question 1: In-Game Name?```");


      }

  } else {

      if (message.channel.type === "dm" && authorId in userApplications) {
          let authorApplication = userApplications[authorId];

          if (authorApplication.step == 1 ) {
              repliestemp.push(message.content); // PUSH THE ANSWER TO ARRAY
              console.log(message.content);
              console.log(repliestemp);
              message.author.send("```Question 2: Bug?```");
              authorApplication.step ++;
          }
          else if (authorApplication.step == 2) {
              repliestemp.push(message.content); // PUSH THE ANSWER TO ARRAY
              console.log(message.content);
              console.log(repliestemp);
              message.author.send("```Question 3: How it occurred?```");
              authorApplication.step ++;
          }
          else if (authorApplication.step == 3) {
              repliestemp.push(message.content); // PUSH THE ANSWER TO ARRAY
              console.log(message.content);
              console.log(repliestemp);
              message.author.send("```Question 4: What Exactly Was Happening Before/When It Occurred?```");
              authorApplication.step ++;
          }
          else if (authorApplication.step == 4) {
              repliestemp.push(message.content); // PUSH THE ANSWER TO ARRAY
              console.log(message.content);
              console.log(repliestemp);
              message.author.send("```Question 4: Planet Where It Occurred?```");
              authorApplication.step ++;
          }
          else if (authorApplication.step == 5) {
              repliestemp.push(message.content); // PUSH THE ANSWER TO ARRAY
              console.log(message.content);
              console.log(repliestemp);
              message.author.send("```Question 4: Date?```");
              authorApplication.step ++;
          }
          else if (authorApplication.step == 6) {
              repliestemp.push(message.content); // PUSH THE ANSWER TO ARRAY
              console.log(message.content);
              console.log(repliestemp);
              message.author.send("```Thanks for your bug report. Please do not report the same bug again, every single bug report is recorded and considered```");
              const exampleEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
              .setColor('RANDOM')
              .setTitle('BUG REPORT')
              .addField('Reported By', `${message.author.tag} with an ID: ${message.author.id}`)
              .addField('In game name', repliestemp[0] || '__*Question Not Answered By User Or Attached File/Photo*__')
              .addField('Bug', repliestemp[1] || '__*Question Not Answered By User Or Attached File/Photo*__')
              .addField('How it occurred', repliestemp[2] || '__*Question Not Answered By User Or Attached File/Photo*__')
              .addField('What Exactly Was Happening Before/When It Occurred', repliestemp[3] || '__*Question Not Answered By User Or Attached File/Photo*__')
              .addField('Planet Where It Occurred', repliestemp[4] || '__*Question Not Answered By User Or Attached File/Photo*__')
              .addField('Date', repliestemp[5] || '__*Question Not Answered By User Or Attached File/Photo*__')
              .setTimestamp()

              const channel = client.channels.get('652930225973362718');
              channel.send(exampleEmbed);
              delete userApplications[authorId];
              repliestemp.length = 0; // EMPTY ARRAY

          }

      }
  }

});```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for here is [awaitMessages](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/11.5.1/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=awaitMessages). The easiest method for me is creating an object and saving responses from that user into that object and then displaying the captured content from the object. Here is an example of a function you can use to await a message from a DM:

```
    return new Promise(async resolve => {
      const filter = m => m.author.id === user.id;
      const messages = await user.dmChannel.awaitMessages(filter, { max: 1, time: 60000 * 60 * 24 });

      resolve(messages.first());
    });
}
```

You are going to want to call this function after the command has been ran, so in your case your command would look something similar to this:

```
if (message.content === "!report -testbug"){
 //define your function here or in your client.on('message')...
 const user = message.member
 const c = message.channel
 const product = {};
 let m;
 c.send('') //fill in with your questions etc
 m = await awaitDM(c,user)
 product['message1] = m.first();
}
```

Hope this helps you because it definitely helped me. You can also configure this to work with a configuration file and questions to make your code shorter and more flexible (adding questions, removing them, editing them, etc from one config file)